# Always getting "Fetch Cycle Limit Reached" while setting up new project in Force.com IDE

Tags: force.com-ide

I am unable to setup project in Force.com IDE and it gives me Fetch cycle limit reached error always. I even tried to tweak my eclipse.ini to use more memory, but still getting error.
[image]

More info:

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Force.com IDE v38.0
(JDK)java version "1.8.0"
```

Has anybody encountered the same error and got it resolved? Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you're trying to select too much metadata. You can either click [Continue] to keep waiting, or [Abort] and choose a smaller set of data to pull from the server. This can also happen if a deployment is happening while you try to retrieve, since it typically has to wait behind the deployment in the metadata API queue. In that case, try, try again.

Comment: I did not select too much metadata. I chose only basic metadata Apex Classes, triggers, pages, static resources. I tried couple of times, but no luck.

Comment: @user41417 Then it's likely the other option. You're apparently stuck in the metadata API queue. Are there deployments going on in your org? Are you running tests? If all else fails, you might need to submit a case to support, as it ordinarily shouldn't take more than 10 minutes to refresh just the basic code.

Comment: Remove the static resource and then give a try:)